# Using an external microphone with iPad Air or the new iPad Mini

Tags: ipad, microphone

I have an external USB microphone that works fine with the iPad 3 using the Camera Connection USB adapter and a USB hub for power. Can a similar setup be used for the new generation of iPads?

Edit: Just to be clear, an answer with practical experience or a link to someone who has verified this setup is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, yes, it should still work fine. However, as I'm sure you're aware the iPad 3 does not have the Lightning connector. You will need to purchase a [Lightning to USB Camera Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD821ZM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter) so that you can connect your USB device to the new iPads with Lightning connectors.

Comment: I'm more worried about the practical bit; theoretically a lot of things ought to work, but since Apple doesn't officially support them (and yet, it works in Garageband...), I'm a bit weary about plonking down a lot of money on new devices before someone who was verified it answers. Thanks for your time, though :)

Comment: Bought Lightning-to-USB Camera Adapter, tested to work on iPad Mini 1G.

Comment: Also tested to work on a iPad 3rd gen (Retina iPad)